# Reading Multiple Lines from a Text File using batch

Tags: batch-file

i am having following file with certificate data

```
###################
The signature is timestamped: Wed Nov 30 18:19:59 2016

Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: Thawte Timestamping CA

    Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA

    Expires:   Fri Jan 01 05:29:59 2021

    SHA1 hash: BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656
###################
```

I am looking for help in batch script to filter out values of

1. The signature is timestamped:
2. SHA1 hash:

Can anyone please help me ?

I tried following, but not good:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (result.txt) do (
  echo line=%%a
)
pause
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Another option

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "timestamped="
    set "hash="

    :: Token positions inside the lines:
    ::
    ::    1a  2b        3c 4d           5e   
    ::    The signature is timestamped: Wed Nov 30 18:19:59 2016
    ::        1a   2b    3c
    ::        SHA1 hash: BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656

    for /f "tokens=1-4,*" %%a in ('
        findstr /l 
            /c:"The signature is timestamped:"
            /c:"SHA1 hash:"
            "result.txt"
    ') do if "%%d"=="timestamped:" ( 
        set "timestamped=%%e" 
    ) else (
        set "hash=%%c"
    )

    echo timestamped %timestamped% 
    echo hash        %hash%
```

This filters the file (`findstr`) to only retrieve the needed lines from the file. The `for /f` processes those lines retrieving the requested tokens.

Answer (score 1):

try this (not tested):

```
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('find "The signature is timestamped:" "result.txt" ') do (
   set "timestamped=%%b"
)

for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('find "SHA1 hash" "result.txt" ') do (
   set "hash=%%b"
)

echo %timestamped% -- %hash%
```

Comment: The space following the colons will be part of the var contents.So `echo:"%timestamped:~1%" -- "%hash:~1%"` should account for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following script, let us call it `extract.bat`, does what you are asking for. It regards only lines that lie in between the first and second line containing `###################`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FRAME=###################"
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (use file provided by command line argument)
set "_SEARCH[1]=The signature is timestamped:"
set "_SEARCH[2]=SHA1 hash:"
rem "_SEARCH[...]=...:"

rem // Determine numbers of first and second lines containing string `%_FRAME%`:
set "FRST=" & set "SCND="
for /F "delims=:" %%K in ('
    findstr /N /C:"%_FRAME%" "%_FILE%"
') do (
    if not defined FRST (
        set /A "FRST=%%K"
    ) else (
        if not defined SCND set /A "SCND=%%K"
    )
)
rem // Continue only if two lines have been found containing string `%_FRAME%`:
if defined FRST if defined SCND (
    rem // Enumerate all search strings `_SEARCH[?]` in alphabetical order:
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%I in ('2^> nul set _SEARCH[') do (
        rem // Process currently iterated search string:
        for /F "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%L in ('
            findstr /N /C:"%%J" "%_FILE%"
        ') do (
            rem // Check if current line lies in between the two derived before:
            if %%L GTR %FRST% if %%L LSS %SCND% (
                rem // Return remaining string value with leading spaces removed:
                for /F "tokens=*" %%O in ("%%N") do echo(%%O
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Provide your text file as a command line argument, like:

```cmd
extract.bat "result.txt"
```

If you want to process the data in between the second and third line containing `###################`, change the line...:

```cmd
for /F "delims=:" %%K in ('
```

...to:

```cmd
for /F "skip=1 delims=:" %%K in ('
```

Increment the `skip` number accordingly for processing the next block.

---

If you do not care about the `###################` lines (in case your text file does not contain multiple blocks of data), the script can be simplified to this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (use file provided by command line argument)
set "_SEARCH[1]=The signature is timestamped:"
set "_SEARCH[2]=SHA1 hash:"
rem "_SEARCH[...]=...:"

rem // Enumerate all search strings `_SEARCH[?]` in alphabetical order:
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%I in ('2^> nul set _SEARCH[') do (
    rem // Process currently iterated search string:
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%M in ('
        findstr /C:"%%J" "%_FILE%"
    ') do (
        rem // Return remaining string value with leading spaces removed:
        for /F "tokens=*" %%O in ("%%N") do echo(%%O
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```